# How to disable postcode, city and street as required fields in checkout

Tags: checkout, eav

We developed a Magento module for creating simple landing-pages for free downloadable products. We programmatically create an order model and save it to the database. As long as we populate street, city, and postcode to the model - we're fine.

But to make it easy for customers to purchase the free download, we don't want the street, postcode, and city as required fields.

We tried rewriting validate() in customer/address_abstract and we set all eav-customer-attributes to be not required in eav_attributes table. But that still didn't help.

Any recommendation in which direction we could go to resolve this issue?

EDIT:
Fixed. No rewrite necessary, no fields have to be changed in the database. As long as we pass country and region it's working now.

Comment: Be sure to add your solution as an answer and accept it. Keeps the stats of the site up and is helpful for future googlers :)

Comment: You may want to add your edit as an answer and accept it.